# Accessing a deeper level document if email is found along the way in cloud firestore

Tags: firebase-security

I'm a teacher who has built a webapp for my school to store assessment data basically. The database has this structure:

```
matrix -> mStudents -> mStudents--active -> *STUDENT* -> courseList -> *COURSE* -> assessments -> *ASSESSMENT*
```

there are many STUDENT documents, and each have a few COURSE documents, and each have a few ASSESSMENT documents - this is where the grade data is. Initially, I allowed teachers to write freely, but I want to up the security level a bit and allow teachers to only write in COURSE documents (and deeper than that) that have their email listed in them. Here is what I've tried:

### Attempt #1

```
match /matrix/mStudents/mStudents--active/{studentDoc=**} {
 allow write: if request.auth.token.email == resource.data.teacher_email;
}
```

This would work(?) if all the ASSESSMENT documents also had teacher_email in them, but I would much rather prefer a cleaner solution.

### Attempt #2

```
  match /matrix/mStudents/mStudents--active/{student}/courseList/{course=**} {
        allow write: if request.auth.token.email == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/matrix/mStudents/mStudents--active/$(course)).data.teacher_email;
}
```

I feel like this should work but alas no luck here. Maybe the recursive wildcard can't be used as a variable?

**This is basically my question then: is it possible to access a deeper document by retrieving user credentials along the way, or should I just try to use attempt #1?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your failed attempt you are missing the student collection within the get

Try this:

```
match /matrix/mStudents/mStudents--active/{student}/courseList/{course} {
  allow write: if request.auth.token.email == resource.data.teacher_email;
}

 match /matrix/mStudents/mStudents--active/{student}/courseList/{course}/assessments/{assessment} {
   allow write: if request.auth.token.email == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/matrix/mStudents/mStudents--active/$(student)/courseList/$(course)).data.teacher_email;
}
```

Comment: So I need to basically write a match function for each level that I want them to be able to write in, am I understanding you correctly?

Wouldn't it be possible to replace the assessments collection with a recursive wildcard to indicate that it should cover all that follows?

Comment: Any special reason you want to use a recursive wildcard? In my opinion, the more precise the rules the more secure, using recursive wildcards often add loopholes (in the example you give, any level of collection under the wildcard could be written to)

Comment: No just readability I guess. Anyway I got it work with your input. Thanks!